# Excel Conditonal Formatting discrepensy

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to figure out a conditional formatting formula to fit this below.

I need Cell A145 to be conditional formatted to meet the following requirements:
Highlight A145 Red if:

A145>1.5
OR 
A145<.8
AND
A142-A143 is greater than 3

[image]

Comment: The AND part is a must? I mean, you want to check always that? Or only if A145 <.8?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Agreed, parentheses would help clarify. I made my best guess...

Comment: @BigBen Yeah. OP needs to clarify, but your formula looks good for me. Let's see what OP got to say

Comment: Yes. It has to be less than .8 and a difference greater than 3 to highlight red, or greater than 1.5 and a difference greater than 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

`=AND(OR(A145>1.5,A145<.8),A142-A143>3)`